# Why do StAX readers and writers not close the underlying input source?

Tags: java

According to StAX XMLEventReader, XMLEventWriter, XMLStreamReader, XMLStreamWriter API close() method does not close the uderlying resource. Thus this code

```
XMLInputFactory xf = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xr = xf.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("1.xml"));
...
xr.close();
```

which seems safe at first glance results in a resource leak.

Does anybody know a use case when not closing the underlying resource could be useful?

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. Not constructive.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634442/why-do-stax-readers-and-writers-not-implement-closeable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What comes to mind is socket-based communication, where several XML documents are sent and received, and closing the underlying stream would close the socket.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I've just been digging into XMLStreamReader and XMLInputFactory implementations and it looks to me as if "close" is horribly misnamed; it's more of a "reset" allowing the factory to reuse that instance on a subsequent create call if a (non-default) config flag is set.

Note also that some implementations DO close the underlying resource - http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6539065 . I'm leaning toward not calling close on these things at all.

Comment: @mrec Unfortunately, as that bug demonstrates it, "some implementations" will call `close()` whether you like it or not.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, because after reaching end of document all implementations close the reader.